# How do I "inherit" traits when wrapping a struct?

Tags: rust

I want to play waves generated by the waver crate via the rodio crate. To generate waves, waver provides the `WaveIterator` struct. To play sound, rodio provides the `OutputStreamHandle`, which takes a `Source`. `Source` is a trait, which can be implemented, so my genius plan was to just take `WaveIterator` and let it implement `Source`.

But my plan was foiled, because I can't implement traits for structs from other classes. Not to worry, I found something called the newtype pattern, which wraps a struct, in my case `WaveIterator` in another struct, and I can implement `Source` for that.

But now the compiler complains, that my struct is not an iterator, because `Source` expects an iterator. I thought, maybe implementing Deref and DerefMut would solve that problem, but it didn't. Has it maybe something to do with the lifetime annotation of `WaveIterator`?

So what do I do now? I don't want to reimplement every trait from WaveIterator manually for my wrapper struct. Is there a way to "inherit" the traits from the wrapped struct? Or am I doing this completely wrong?

Comment: Prefer showing the code that you have so far and reproduces the problem. Also, considering that you already implemented `Source`, what stopped you from implementing `Iterator`?

Comment: Yeah, I just did that. But it doesn't feel that elegant

Comment: Implementing all the necessary traits on the newtype is the idiomatic way. One can also use a derive macro crate such as [`newtype-derive-2018`](https://crates.io/crates/newtype-derive-2018) or [`newtype-ops`](https://crates.io/crates/newtype-ops) to reduce the boilerplate.

Comment: @E_net4ismydisplayname Agreed, see also: [RFC 2393: Delegation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2393) (backlogged as of now).